# My laptop tries to eject my graphic card but can't so it freezes

Tags: windows-7, laptop, graphics-card, nvidia-graphics-card, nvidia-geforce

Everytime, I try to start "Batman Arkham Knight" my laptop freezes and shows me an error message like that:

> The "Nvidia Geforce GTX 680M" device is not removable and cannot be ejected or unplugged.

This message appears in a single window and windows is freezed after that. I have to hard shutdown my machine.

Other games are playable, but not Batman Arkham Knight. I tried to start it directly using my dedicated graphic card but it did not work.

I have the most recent drivers installed: HD Graphics 4000: 10.18.10.4425 and NVIDIA GeForce GTX 680M: 21.21.13.7633

Comment: You don't have the most recent [Intel](https://downloadcenter.intel.com/download/25977/Intel-Graphics-Driver-for-Windows-10-and-Windows-7-8-1-15-33-) drivers installed.  Are you sure you have 376.33 installed?

Comment: @Ramhound: I have the most recent driver *for my graphic chip*. The version you suggest does not support the 4000 anymore.

Comment: It says it supports your Intel GPU right on the page. I know for a fact it supports it.  Your Intel GPU drivers are OUT OF DATE.  I have the exact same GPU, running Windows 10, with the drivers I linked to installed.  `10.18.10.4425` isn't is several years old.

Comment: I installed your linked version but it didn't change the version number given in the device manager. Both have the same build version (4425) so I assume this is fine.

Comment: If its still reporting as `10.18.10.4425` it means you still have the old driver installed.

Answer (score 1):

You need to downgrade to an older NVidia driver.

> Luckily, I was able to download an older driver from the NVIDIA web
>   site, dated from before I last successfully produced a video on this
>   same computer. Driver version: 361.43. I simply ran the driver
>   install, without first uninstalling anything. The driver install
>   overwrote the newer driver without touching the other components of
>   the NVIDIA install and without messing up my custom configuration.
>   This has solved the issue for me.
>
> had exactly the same issue while running matrix calculations on Maple
>   with the GTX 765M. I downloaded and installed an older driver version
>   (364.72), which eliminated the issue. So I imagine there is a
>   compatibility problem between Maple and the newest driver version
>   (368.39).

["The Nvidia Geforce GTX 670M device is not removable and cannot be ejected or unplugged."](http://www.tomsguide.com/answers/id-3061677/nvidia-geforce-gtx-670m-device-removable-ejected-unplugged.html)

Solution: You need to install **[361.43](http://www.nvidia.com/download/driverResults.aspx/96883/en-us)**

Since the Arkham Knight Game Ready Driver was released in June, as 353.30, installing 361.43 should solve your problem.

Comment: The linked driver is for windows 10 but I use windows 7 as tagged. I can not find the given version for my notebook graphic card. Although, I already tried some older drivers and they did not work either.

Comment: @tjati - The version I linked to supports notebook graphic cards.